# Google Places: Android API: Place class missing some data

Tags: android, json, google-places-api

I find that Place class from Android Library for Google Places API misses a lot of data which is available in Web-Service API.

Android class:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place

Web-Service reply:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details?hl=en

For example, class definition has nothing about Reviews or Opening Hours. Why it is so? Is it possible to fix it without converting all the app to Web-Service API calls and json-parsing? Perhaps there is an ability to convert Place object to its raw JSON-form to find some additional data?

Comment: Finally decided to avoid using Google Android API where its data is not complete

Answer (score 0):

Places api in android only returns a few details like place name, latitude, longitude etc. if you want more details you have to call webservice api . This is the URl

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key={API_KEY}&placeid={PLACE_ID}
```

Here PLACE_ID will get from Place Object in Android Places Api

Sample output:

```
 {
                                                               "html_attributions" : [],
                                                               "result" : {
                                                                  "address_components" : [
                                                                     {
                                                                        "long_name" : "7167",
                                                                        "short_name" : "7167",
                                                                        "types" : [ "street_number" ]
                                                                     },
                                                                     {
                                                                        "long_name" : "Sunset Boulevard",
                                                                        "short_name" : "Sunset Blvd",
                                                                        "types" : [ "route" ]
                                                                     },
                                                                     {
                                                                        "long_name" : "Central LA",
                                                                        "short_name" : "Central LA",
                                                                        "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
                                                                     },
                                                                     {
                                                                        "long_name" : "Los Angeles",
                                                                        "short_name" : "Los Angeles",
                                                                        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                                                                     },
                                                                     {
                                                                        "long_name" : "Los Angeles County",
                                                                        "short_name" : "Los Angeles County",
                                                                        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
                                                                     },
                                                                     {
                                                                        "long_name" : "California",
                                                                        "short_name" : "CA",
                                                                        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
                                                                     },
                                                                     {
                                                                        "long_name" : "United States",
                                                                        "short_name" : "US",
                                                                        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
                                                                     },
                                                                     {
                                                                        "long_name" : "90046",
                                                                        "short_name" : "90046",
                                                                        "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
                                                                     }
                                                                  ],
                                                                  "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"street-address\"\u003e7167 Sunset Blvd\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eLos Angeles\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eCA\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003e90046\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eUSA\u003c/span\u003e",
                                                                  "formatted_address" : "7167 Sunset Blvd, Los Angeles, CA 90046, USA",
                                                                  "geometry" : {
                                                                     "location" : {
                                                                        "lat" : 34.098341,
                                                                        "lng" : -118.346263
                                                                     },
                                                                     "viewport" : {
                                                                        "northeast" : {
                                                                           "lat" : 34.0995122302915,
                                                                           "lng" : -118.3449154697085
                                                                        },
                                                                        "southwest" : {
                                                                           "lat" : 34.0968142697085,
                                                                           "lng" : -118.3476134302915
                                                                        }
                                                                     }
                                                                  },
                                                                  "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
                                                                  "id" : "7143e0743707f66cfa1cda945779f18e8350060e",
                                                                  "name" : "7167 Sunset Blvd",
                                                                  "place_id" : "ChIJn_0bqti-woARRtpNvG7kuq4",
                                                                  "reference" : "CmRbAAAAuU6CDhPuLqrS9F4XCZIV61wveIeU44RMua7FSCZHtwJeC58_OJksQvLI9Nudb9-N8RhfJDUECkxvdB-llxe6WIqrkDQMBs2vz3mBky0DH70jIcFS7f0_7yivdsxmmLzaEhAtwgzDs0va2soGuFyzuNTGGhR-xVrIvyeZwY0OGDmEp3FJmrbbeQ",
                                                                  "scope" : "GOOGLE",
                                                                  "types" : [ "street_address" ],
                                                                  "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?q=7167+Sunset+Blvd,+Los+Angeles,+CA+90046,+USA&ftid=0x80c2bed8aa1bfd9f:0xaebae46ebc4dda46",
                                                                  "utc_offset" : -420,
                                                                  "vicinity" : "Los Angeles"
                                                               },
                                                               "status" : "OK"
                                                            }
```

Sample JSON Parsing in android

```
String postalCode="";
                    String city="";
                    String state="";
                    String address="";

                    JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(rs);
                    JSONArray addressComponents = jsonObj.getJSONObject("result").getJSONArray("address_components");
                    for(int i = 0; i < addressComponents.length(); i++) {
                        JSONArray typesArray = addressComponents.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("types");
                        for (int j = 0; j < typesArray.length(); j++) {
                            if (typesArray.get(j).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("postal_code")) {
                               postalCode = addressComponents.getJSONObject(i).getString("long_name");
                            }else if (typesArray.get(j).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("locality")) {
                                city = addressComponents.getJSONObject(i).getString("long_name");
                            }else if (typesArray.get(j).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("administrative_area_level_1")) {
                                state = addressComponents.getJSONObject(i).getString("long_name");
                            }else {
                                String types=typesArray.get(j).toString();
                                if(types.equalsIgnoreCase("street_number")
                                        ||types.equalsIgnoreCase("route")
                                        ||types.equalsIgnoreCase("neighborhood")
                                        ||types.equalsIgnoreCase("sublocality_level_1")

                                        )
                                address+=addressComponents.getJSONObject(i).getString("long_name")+", ";
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: As you may know Google Android API is cheaper (larger usage limits). Do you know if they plan to extend own Android library? Any official channels of news, etc?

Comment: Don't have any news regarding this. May be they will update their library for places and direction APIs.